# Woocommerce: Editing Header

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I would like to edit code in header of a [woocommerce site](http://isotopethemes.com/wp-test/), I want to know where the code for 'Welcome, User' and 'Cart' comes from, I'm trying to add cart weight to header, I got the code which generates the cart weight but I can't seem to find where these files are, they are not in header.php.

Edit: header.php does has the files but there are sub files from where these things come up:

Code of header.php file:

```
 <?php





//Add body classes

$body_classes = 'no_js';

if( ( yit_get_option( 'responsive-enabled' ) && !$GLOBALS['is_IE'] ) || ( yit_get_option( 'responsive-enabled' ) && yit_ie_version() >= 9 ) ) {

    $body_classes .= ' responsive';

}



//Enabled dropdown in widgets

if( yit_get_option('enable-sidebar-dropdown') ) {

    $body_classes .= ' yit_widget_dropdown';

}



$body_classes .= ' ' . yit_get_option( 'layout-type' );

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if IE 6]>

<html id="ie6" class="ie"<?php language_attributes() ?> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>

<html id="ie7"  class="ie"<?php language_attributes() ?> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>

<html id="ie8"  class="ie"<?php language_attributes() ?> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>

<html id="ie9"  class="ie"<?php language_attributes() ?> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<![endif]-->



<!-- This doesn't work but i prefer to leave it here... maybe in the future the MS will support it... i hope... -->

<!--[if IE 10]>

<html id="ie10"  class="ie"<?php language_attributes() ?> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<![endif]-->



<!--[if gt IE 9]>

<html class="ie"<?php language_attributes() ?> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<![endif]-->



<![if !IE]>

<html <?php language_attributes() ?> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<![endif]>



<!-- START HEAD -->

<head>

    <?php do_action( 'yit_head' ) ?> 

    <?php wp_head() ?>

</head>

<!-- END HEAD -->

<!-- START BODY -->

<body <?php body_class( $body_classes ) ?>>



    <!-- START BG SHADOW -->

    <div class="bg-shadow">



        <?php do_action( 'yit_before_wrapper' ) ?>

        <!-- START WRAPPER -->

        <div id="wrapper" class="container group">



            <?php do_action( 'yit_before_header' ) ?>

            <!-- START HEADER -->

            <div id="header" class="group<?php if( yit_get_header_skin() == 'skin1' && yit_get_option('show-header-search') ): ?> header_with_search<?php endif ?> margin-bottom">

                <?php

                do_action( 'yit_header' ) ?>

            </div>

            <!-- END HEADER -->

            <?php

            do_action( 'yit_after_header' ) ?>
```

Comment: It is wrapped up in to the `header` tag so it might link to other file from header. Can you show the code of `header.php` ?

Comment: thank you for replying, header.php does gives out the header but it calls a bunch of file, I'll post code you can have a look.

Comment: So its done with the `do_action( 'yit_header' )` .So search for that action.It might be in `functions.php` or any other related file.

Comment: It's not in functions.php but I've found out the location where the files are present.

Comment: Great ! Good Luck with it :)